# How do I center polygon on map on default load in QWC QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qwc2

How do I make themesConfig.json pick the extent defined in the qgs file and have it center the extent instead of centering the entire map, which leaves the `extent` a drift to the right of the viewport?

Tried editing the config.json file to no avail? Alternatively where would I pass $st parameter on default load of page so it loads the search result by default on visiting the client?